# Azure APIM Mock Response not showing headers in Response

Tags: azure, apim

I have a mock response with these headers and content

[image]

this is the content of my policy

[image]

but when I test it, it does not include headers

[image]

This is what I see in the trace

[image]

How can I include these headers in the response?